# Using big dates in c#

Tags: c#, date

I need to manage big dates, since universe creation (-15 000 000 000 to now). DateTime only allows to work from 0001/01/01 to 9999/12/31. (I don't need month-day-hour-etc.. resolution before 1000 BC). Is there a free library/class working with big dates ? 
Best regards

Comment: I doubt there would be, there's no practical use for having one. You don't need that fine precision, so just keep track of the year. longs are adequate for that purpose.

Comment: even if milliseconds are interesting at begining of universe.

Comment: Check https://nodatime.org/ project

Comment: even if milliseconds are interesting at begining of universe.

Comment: Thanks for NodaTime, but in this lib, year are int, so lowest value is -2147483648, and not enough for -15 000 000 000;

Comment: @Backs: No, we don't support dates before 9998BC.

Comment: "even if milliseconds are interesting at begining of universe" - your question states "I don't need month-day-hour-etc.. resolution before 1000 BC" which seems to contradict that. You'd need to be *really* specific and clear about your requirements for anyone to be able to help you, but this question is off-topic as it's a request for a library or other off-site resource anyway.

Comment: This can actually be a good, interesting question if you where not looking for an off-site resource - as Jon wrote, this is off-topic to stackoverflow, and anyway, that's what search engines are for. If you want to ask for ways to improve your current implementation - if it's working as expected, than post a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If it has specific bugs, ask for help with these bugs here.

Comment: I don't understand your point of view. When somebody ask, as on suggestion at right of the page, "How do I enumerate an enum in C#", is it a bug, or help on software ? What is the difference with "How to use date/time since -16 Billions years because Windows and Linux don't give standard library for that ?

Comment: "Is there a free library/class working with big dates" - You're asking us to help you find a code library - which is not a bad question but it is off-topic to stackoverflow. Asking how to do a specific task is on-topic. Asking for debugging help is also on-topic. Asking for improvements of a working code is more suited to CodeReview.

Comment: Ok, thank your for patience and pedagogy. I will try on CodeReview. But during this time, I have written a BigDate class, using System.Numerics.BigInteger : This is working correctly. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose this part of solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.ComponentModel;

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class cBigDate : ICloneable {

    public object Clone() {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }

    public cBigDate() {
        IsNull = true;
        }

    public cBigDate(DateTime dt) {
        IsNull = false;
        Year = dt.Year;
        Month = dt.Month;
        Day = dt.Day;
        Hour = dt.Hour;
        Minute = dt.Minute;
        Second = dt.Second;
        Millisecond = dt.Millisecond;
        }

    public cBigDate(BigInteger y, BigInteger m, BigInteger d, BigInteger h, BigInteger mi, BigInteger s, BigInteger ms) {
        IsNull = false;
        Year = y;
        Month = m;
        Day = d;
        Hour = h;
        Minute = mi;
        Second = s;
        Millisecond = ms;
        }

    public cBigDate(BigInteger y, BigInteger m, BigInteger d) {
        IsNull = false;
        Year = y;
        Month = m;
        Day = d;
        Hour = 0;
        Minute = 0;
        Second = 0;
        Millisecond = 0;
        }

    public cBigDate(BigInteger y, BigInteger m) {
        IsNull = false;
        Year = y;
        Month = m;
        Day = 1;
        Hour = 0;
        Minute = 0;
        Second = 0;
        Millisecond = 0;
        }

    public cBigDate(BigInteger y) {
        IsNull = false;
        Year = y;
        Month = 1;
        Day = 1;
        Hour = 0;
        Minute = 0;
        Second = 0;
        Millisecond = 0;
        }

    public void addSpan(BigInteger y, BigInteger m, BigInteger d, BigInteger h, BigInteger mi, BigInteger s, BigInteger ms) {
        do {
            addMillisecond(ms);
            addSecond(s);
            addMinute(mi);
            addHour(h);
            addDay(d);
            addMonth(m);
            addYear(y);
            IsNull = false;
            }
        while (false);
        }

    public void addSpan(BigInteger y) {
        do {
            addYear(y);
            IsNull = false;
            }
        while (false);
        }

    public void addDuration( cDuration d) {
        do {
            addMillisecond(d.Millisecond);
            addSecond(d.Second);
            addMinute(d.Minute);
            addHour(d.Hour);
            addDay(d.Day);
            addMonth(d.Month);
            addYear(d.Year);
            IsNull = false;
            }
        while (false);
        }


    public static BigInteger _msInSecond = (BigInteger)1e3;

    public static BigInteger _msInMinute = (BigInteger)1e3 * (BigInteger)60;

    public static BigInteger _msInHour = (BigInteger)1e3 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)60;

    public static BigInteger _msInDay = (BigInteger)1e3 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)24;

    public static BigInteger _msInYear = (BigInteger)1e3 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)24 * (BigInteger)365;

    public static BigInteger _msInLeapYear = (BigInteger)1e3 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)60 * (BigInteger)24 * (BigInteger)366;


    public BigInteger TotalMillisecond() {

        BigInteger result = 0;

        result += millisecond;
        result += second * _msInSecond;
        result += minute * _msInMinute;
        result += hour * _msInHour;
        result += (DayInYear() - 1) * _msInDay;
        result += LeapYearsBefore(year) * _msInLeapYear;
        result += NoLeapYearsBefore(year) * _msInYear;

        return result;
        }

    public void addDuration(BigInteger pMillisecond) {

        do {
            BigInteger nbYear = pMillisecond / _msInYear;
            addYear(nbYear);

            BigInteger leftYear = pMillisecond % _msInYear;

            BigInteger nbDay = leftYear / _msInDay;
            addDay(nbDay);
            BigInteger leftDay = leftYear % _msInDay;

            BigInteger nbHour = leftDay / _msInHour;
            addHour(nbHour);
            BigInteger leftHour = leftDay % _msInHour;

            BigInteger nbMinute = leftHour / _msInMinute;
            addMinute(nbMinute);
            BigInteger leftMinute = leftHour % _msInMinute;

            BigInteger nbSecond = leftMinute / _msInSecond;
            addSecond(nbSecond);
            BigInteger leftSecond = leftMinute % _msInSecond;

            addMillisecond(leftSecond);
            }
        while (false);
        }

    public void addYear(BigInteger pYear) {
        BigInteger oldYear = year;
        Year += pYear;
        if (oldYear.Sign == 1 && year.Sign == -1) {
            Year--;
            }
        else if (oldYear.Sign == -1 && year.Sign == 1) {
            Year++;
            }
        }

    public void addMonth(BigInteger pMonth) {
        BigInteger value = pMonth.Abs();
        BigInteger sign = pMonth.Sign;
        while (value > 0) {
            Month = Month + sign;
            if (Month == 0) {
                Month = 12;
                Year--;
                }
            else if (Month == 13) {
                Month = 1;
                Year++;
                }
            value--;
            }
        }

    public void addDay(BigInteger pDay) {
        BigInteger value = pDay.Abs();
        BigInteger sign = pDay.Sign;
        while (value > 0) {
            Day = Day + sign;
            if (Day == 0) {
                addMonth(-1);
                Day = MaxDayOfMonth(Month, Year);
                }
            else if (Day == (MaxDayOfMonth(Month, Year)+1) ) {
                addMonth(1);
                Day = 1;
                }
            value--;
            }
        }

    public void addHour(BigInteger pHour) {
        BigInteger value = pHour.Abs();
        BigInteger sign = pHour.Sign;
        while (value > 0) {
            Hour = Hour + sign;
            if (Hour == -1) {
                addDay(-1);
                Hour = 23;
                }
            else if (Hour == 24) {
                addDay(1);
                Hour = 0;
                }
            value--;
            }
        }

    public void addMinute(BigInteger pMinute) {
        BigInteger value = pMinute.Abs();
        BigInteger sign = pMinute.Sign;
        while (value > 0) {
            Minute = Minute + sign;
            if (Minute == -1) {
                addHour(-1);
                Minute = 59;
                }
            else if (Minute == 60) {
                addHour(1);
                Minute = 0;
                }
            value--;
            }
        }

    public void addSecond(BigInteger pSecond) {
        BigInteger value = pSecond.Abs();
        BigInteger sign = pSecond.Sign;
        while (value > 0) {
            Second = Second + sign;
            if (Second == -1) {
                addMinute(-1);
                Second = 59;
                }
            else if (Second == 60) {
                addMinute(1);
                Second = 0;
                }
            value--;
            }
        }

    public void addMillisecond(BigInteger pMillisecond) {
        BigInteger value = pMillisecond.Abs();
        BigInteger sign = pMillisecond.Sign;
        while (value > 0) {
            Millisecond = Millisecond + sign;
            if (Millisecond == -1) {
                addSecond(-1);
                Millisecond = 999;
                }
            else if (Millisecond == 1000) {
                addSecond(1);
                Millisecond = 0;
                }
            value--;
            }
        }

    public BigInteger MaxDayOfMonth(BigInteger m, BigInteger y) {
        BigInteger maxDayOfMonth = 0;
        do {
            BigInteger[] dayInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

            if (m < 1 || m > 12)
                break;

            maxDayOfMonth = dayInMonth[ (int)m - 1];
            if (IsLeapYear(y) && m == 2) {
                maxDayOfMonth += 1;
                }
            }
        while (false);

        return maxDayOfMonth;
        }

    public static BigInteger DateTimeToMillisecond(DateTime dt) {

        return dt.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        }

    public DateTime ToDateTime() {
        return new DateTime((int)year, (int)month, (int)day, (int)hour, (int)minute, (int)second, (int)millisecond, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
    /*
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoYear;
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoMonth;
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoDay;
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoHour;
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoMinute;
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoSecond;
    [JsonProperty]
    public long _memoMillisecond;
    [JsonProperty]
    public Boolean _memoIsNull;*/

    BigInteger year;
    public BigInteger _leapYearsBefore = 0;
    public BigInteger _noLeapYearsBefore = 0;
    public BigInteger Year {
        get {
            return year;
            }
        set {
            year = value;
            //_memoYear = (long)year;
            _leapYearsBefore = LeapYearsBefore(year);
            _noLeapYearsBefore = NoLeapYearsBefore(year);
            }
        }

    BigInteger month;
    public BigInteger Month {
        get {
            return month;
            }
        set {
            month = value;
            //_memoMonth = (long)month;
            }
        }

    BigInteger day;
    public BigInteger Day {
        get {
            return day;
            }
        set {
            day = value;
            //_memoDay = (long)day;
            }
        }

    BigInteger hour;
    public BigInteger Hour {
        get {
            return hour;
            }
        set {
            hour = value;
            //_memoHour = (long)hour;
            }
        }

    BigInteger minute;
    public BigInteger Minute {
        get {
            return minute;
            }
        set {
            minute = value;
            //_memoMinute = (long)minute;
            }
        }

    BigInteger second;
    public BigInteger Second {
        get {
            return second;
            }
        set {
            second = value;
            //_memoSecond = (long)second;
            }
        }


    BigInteger millisecond;
    public BigInteger Millisecond {
        get {
            return millisecond;
            }
        set {
            millisecond = value;
            //_memoMillisecond = (long)millisecond;
            }
        }

    public static Boolean IsLeapYear(BigInteger y) {
        Boolean IsLeap = false;
        if (y > 3) {
            if (y % 400 == 0) {
                IsLeap = true;
                }
            else if ((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) {
                IsLeap = true;
                }
            }
        return IsLeap;
        }

    public BigInteger DayInYear() {
        BigInteger diy = 0;
        BigInteger[] dayInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
        int m = 1;
        while (m < month) {

            diy += dayInMonth[m-1];

            if (m == 2 && IsLeapYear(year))
                diy += 1;

            m++;
            }
        diy += day;

        return diy;
        }

    static BigInteger LeapYearsBetween(BigInteger start, BigInteger end) {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(start < end);
        return LeapYearsBefore(end) - LeapYearsBefore(start + 1);
        }

    public static BigInteger LeapYearsBefore(BigInteger yref) {

        BigInteger result = 0;

        yref = yref.Abs();
        if (yref >= 4) {
            yref--;
            result = (yref / (BigInteger)4) - (yref / (BigInteger)100) + (yref / (BigInteger)400);
            }

        return result;
        }

    public static BigInteger NoLeapYearsBefore(BigInteger yref) {

        BigInteger result = 0;

        yref = yref.Abs();
        if (yref >= 4) {
            yref--;
            result = yref - LeapYearsBefore(yref + 1);
            }
        else {
            if (yref > 0) {
                result = yref - 1;
                }
            }

        return result;
        }

    public BigInteger Distance(cBigDate other) {
        BigInteger distanceMS = 0;

        BigInteger dCurrent = 0;
        if (year > 0) {
            dCurrent = TotalMillisecond();
            }
        else {
            cBigDate positiveCurrent = this;
            positiveCurrent.year = -positiveCurrent.year;
            dCurrent = - positiveCurrent.TotalMillisecond();
            }

        BigInteger dOther = 0;
        if (other.year > 0) {
            dOther = other.TotalMillisecond();
            }
        else {
            cBigDate positiveOther = other;
            positiveOther.year = -positiveOther.year;
            dOther = - positiveOther.TotalMillisecond();
            }

        if (dCurrent > 0 && dOther > 0) {
            distanceMS = dCurrent - dOther;
            }
        else if (dCurrent > 0 && dOther < 0) {
            distanceMS = dCurrent + (-dOther);
            }
        else if (dCurrent < 0 && dOther > 0) {
            distanceMS = dCurrent - dOther;
            }

        return distanceMS;
        }

    public static cBigDate Parse(String s) {
        cBigDate r = new cBigDate();
        do {
            try {
                String[] elems = s.Split(new Char[] { '/' });
                if (elems.Count() == 3) {
                    r = new cBigDate(Convert.ToInt64(elems[0]), Convert.ToInt64(elems[1]), Convert.ToInt64(elems[2]) );
                    }
                else if (elems.Count() == 2) {
                    r = new cBigDate(Convert.ToInt64(elems[0]), Convert.ToInt64(elems[1]));
                    }
                else if (elems.Count() == 1) {
                    r = new cBigDate(Convert.ToInt64(elems[0]));
                    }

                break;
                }
            catch (Exception ex2) {
                r = new cBigDate();
                }

            try {
                if (s == "-") {
                    r.IsNull = true;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception ex3) {
                r = new cBigDate();
                }
            }
        while (false);

        return r;
        }

    Boolean isNull = false;
    public Boolean IsNull {
        get {
            return isNull;
            }
        set {
            isNull = value;
            //_memoIsNull = isNull;
            if (isNull) {
                Year = 0;
                Month = 0;
                Day = 0;
                Hour = 0;
                Minute = 0;
                Second = 0;
                Millisecond = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    public String toDisplayString() {
        if ( ! isNull) {

            if ((Month != 1 || Day != 1) && (Hour != 0 || Minute != 0 || Second != 0 || Millisecond != 0)) {
                return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5},{6}", Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond);
                }
            else if ( (Month != 1 || Day != 1) && (Hour == 0 || Minute == 0 || Second == 0 || Millisecond == 0)) {
                return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Year, Month, Day);
                }
            else if ( (Month == 1 && Day == 1) && (Hour == 0 || Minute == 0 || Second == 0 || Millisecond == 0)) {
                return String.Format("{0}", Year);
                }
            else {
                return "?";
                }
            }
        else {
            return "-";
            }
        }

    public String toString( String format) {
        String result = format;
        do {

            if (format.Contains("yyyy")) {
                if (year.Abs().CompareTo( (BigInteger)1e9) >= 0) {
                    result = result.Replace("yyyy", String.Format("{0:N2} B", BigInteger.Divide(year, (BigInteger)1e9) ) );
                    }
                if (year.Abs().CompareTo((BigInteger)1e6) >= 0) {
                    result = result.Replace("yyyy", String.Format("{0:N2} M", BigInteger.Divide(year, (BigInteger)1e6) ) );
                    }
                else {
                    result = result.Replace("yyyy", String.Format("{0}", year));
                    }
                }

            result = result.Replace("MM", String.Format("{0}", month));
            result = result.Replace("dd", String.Format("{0}", day));
            result = result.Replace("HH", String.Format("{0}", hour));
            result = result.Replace("mm", String.Format("{0}", minute));
            result = result.Replace("ss", String.Format("{0}", second));
            result = result.Replace("fff", String.Format("{0}", millisecond));
            }
        while (false);
        return result;
        }

    public String toString() {
        if (!isNull) {
            return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5},{6}", Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond);
            }
        else {
            return "-";
            }
        }

    public String toStringShort() {
        if (!isNull) {
            if ((Month != 1 || Day != 1) && (Hour != 0 || Minute != 0 || Second != 0 || Millisecond != 0)) {
                return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5},{6}", Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond);
                }
            else if ((Month != 1 || Day != 1) && (Hour == 0 || Minute == 0 || Second == 0 || Millisecond == 0)) {
                return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Year, Month, Day);
                }
            else if ((Month == 1 && Day == 1) && (Hour == 0 || Minute == 0 || Second == 0 || Millisecond == 0)) {
                return String.Format("{0}", Year);
                }
            else {
                return "?";
                }
            }
        else {
            return "-";
            }
        }
    }
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may need to roll your own, an idea could be to use a `long`

Then save the your dates as `DateTime.Ticks`

if these are => 0, you can convert to `DateTime` and if < 0 you could use as the number of years before that?

This means you can use a single property.

Comment: Ticks is a long, and is not enough for operation between dates. I have use System.Numerics BigInteger which is able to compute big integer values.

Comment: ok, great, my answer was just an idea to provide the gist. I suspect the implementation would need to be applied to the application and tested.